# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression for Date function

Tags: javascript, eslint

Hi i'm getting *Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression* error from eslint and i can't figure out why. Is my syntax off? Or does this need to be a ternary?

```
export function formatDate(country) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
    if (country === 'US') {
        currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    } else if (['UK','DE', 'AU'].includes(country)) {
        currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options);
    } else {
        ('invalid country code');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the `else` branch. You have parens with a string inside, and nothing else. ESLint says it should be a function call or an assignment, because otherwise it's doing nothing.

Comment: Did you mean to return the values from the branches of the `if`? The function doesn't actually _do_ anything at the moment.

Comment: You either need to return the result from the if-else or use `console.log()` there.

Comment: See the [`no-unused-expressions` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions).

Comment: do you mean fixing it like this 
`
export function formatDateByCountry(country) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
    if (country === 'US') {
        return currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    } else if (['IT', 'FR', 'ES', 'GB', 'DE', 'AU'].includes(country)) {
        return currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options);
    }
    return 'invalid country code';
}
`

Comment: Also note that `currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);` does not do anything useful. It generates the date string, but your code does not save it anywhere or return it from the function.

Comment: @ericoder Yes, although it's probably not the best idea to return an error message to something expecting a formatted date. Rather use some sort of error handling (return `undefined`, throw an `Error`, or use a `Maybe` or `Either` FP pattern) or a default (like the user's current locale (`undefined` when using `toLocaleString()`)).

Answer (score 0):

It's the `else` branch. You have parentheses with a string inside, and nothing else. This does nothing (you could remove it and the behavior of the program would not change), so ESLint says it should be a function call or an assignment, because otherwise it's doing nothing.

You need to either return the value or do something like logging it to the console.

You also generate a formatted date string in the first two branches, but also do nothing with them (ESLint does not flag these because it does not flag function calls in case of side effects). So the function doesn't actually *do* anything at the moment.

You probably meant to return the values from the branches of the `if`:

```js
export function formatDate(country) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const options = { year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric" };
  if (country === "US") {
    return currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  } else if (["UK", "DE", "AU"].includes(country)) {
    return currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options);
  }
  console.error(`Invalid country code: "${country}"`);
}
```

If the country code is invalid, that code logs the error and returns `undefined`. You could do something else if you wanted.

See the [`no-unused-expressions` ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions) for more info.

Comment: I tried writing a unit test in jest for this but got  
Expected pattern: /^d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/, Received string:  "8/16/2023"
describe('Date test', () => {
it('MM/DD/YYYY', () => {
        const result = formatDate('US');
        const expectFormat = /^d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
        expect(result).toMatch(expectFormat);
    });
    it(' DD/MM/YYYY', () => {
        const result = formatDate('AU');
        const expectedFormat = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
        expect(result).toMatch(expectedFormat);
    });
}
Did i miss something?

Comment: You have not escaped the first `d{1,2}` in the "US" case; it is treating it as literal characters instead of a digit token.

Comment: Would it be better to have expected value for MM/DD/YYYY be /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/ and DD/MM/YYYY be /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/

Comment: I am not here for personal support and advice. If you have a new question, please post it as such. [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the place for "best practices" and such. That said, it depends how strict you want it and what exactly you're testing. If it's just testing that the format is as expected, then plain digit tokens should be fine. Unless you make sure to use a wide range of dates, testing the exact numerals won't help much.